# 'meter' vs. 'rhythm': How do their meanings in poetry differ from those in music?

Tags: poetry, meter, music

'meter' and 'rhythm' are termed in [poetry](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58595/difference-between-meter-and-rhythm-in-poetry) and music. So what are their parallels? Their differences?

Source: [*Listening to Music* (2013 7 ed, but ∃ 8 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133954723) by Yale Prof. [Craig Wright](https://yalemusic.yale.edu/people/craig-wright):

> [p. 463] **meter**: the gathering of beats into regular
>   groups
>
> [p. 465] **rhythm**: the organization of time in music,
>   dividing up long spans of time into
>   smaller, more easily comprehended units

Source: [*An Introduction to Literature* (2007 15 ed, but ∃ 16 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205599095)

> [p. 1590] **meter**
>   a pattern of stressed and unstressed syllables. (723–726, 771–775)
>
> [p. 1592:] **rhythm**
>   in poetry, a pattern of stressed and unstressed sounds; in prose, some sort of recurrence (for example, of a motif) at approximately identical intervals. (717–718, 725)

Comment: My opinion is that this is a huge, book-length question for which I have no specific answer. One useful resource is John Hollander's 1956 article *The Music of Poetry*. Another tack would be an advanced search on jstor.org using the keywords *music* and *poetry*.